# Why is windowClient.url comparison not working?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, webapi

I have copied the following example code from notificationClick event documentation. However, the client.focus() method is never called when I am testing, rather than the openWindow. If I remove the `client.url === "/"` comparison though it works.

```js
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
  console.log("On notification click: ", event.notification.tag);
  event.notification.close();

  // This looks to see if the current is already open and
  // focuses if it is
  event.waitUntil(
    self.clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window",
      })
      .then((clientList) => {
        for (const client of clientList) {
          if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client) {
            return client.focus();
          }
        }
        if (self.clients.openWindow) {
          return self.clients.openWindow("/");
        }
      }),
  );
});
```

I have not trying testing with push to a server configured with https. Is this potentially due to some quirk of how the client.url is compared when the host is http://localhost?

Comment: What is the value of `client.url`?

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: So it's not `/`

Comment: Yeah, that is the obvious answer I guess. I was confused though because the openWindow("/") call navigates to `http://localhost:3000/` without specifying the host, and same with a client.navigate("/") call, and the `client.url === "/"` comparison comes from the MDN example code so I thought there was potentially supposed to be something going on to infer/drop the hostname from the url.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this potentially due to some quirk of how the client.url is
> compared when the host is http://localhost?

No.

When you are on localhost the client url is not equal to `/` it is equal to whatever the current url is, probably `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1` possibly also with whatever port you are testing on.

Comment: Yes, the value is coming back as `http://localhost:3000/`. I guess my real question is whether the example code would work when I am not on localhost.  Given that the `openWindow("/")` call navigates to `http://localhost:3000/` without specifying the host, and same with a client.`navigate("/")` call, and the `client.url === "/"` comparison comes from the MDN example code so I thought there was potentially supposed to be something going on to infer/drop the hostname from the value of client.url.

Comment: At this point though I'm guessing that the `client.url === "/"` is just placeholder code that could never return true in any circumstance

Comment: Well it would depend on your set-up, but in general yes - you would adapt the code and you would replace `"/"` with the actual URL of your application's main page. However it could work if the root of your application was `/` - so it could work in some circumstances.